# Importing fortran files to python

Tags: python, eclipse, fortran, fortran77, f2py

This is a very newbie question, but after searching in Google for a while, I haven't been able to find a solution. I'm writing a Python code using Eclipse (in Linux Mint) which needs some routines written in Fortran 77 (the code is in a file named `fortran_code.f`). I've used `f2py` to get the file `fortran_code.so`. This file is in the same folder as the Python code (`../workspace/python_project/src`). The Python code only includes:

```
import fortran_code
a = 10
fortran_code.fortran_subroutine(a)
```

Once an again, the result is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/home/user/Documents/workspace/python_project/src/Main.py", line 7,
in <module>
import fortran_code ImportError: /home/user/Documents/workspace/python_project/src/fortran_code.so:
undefined symbol: PyCObject_Type
```

The Fortran subroutine code is:

```
SUBROUTINE fortran_subroutine(a) 
REAL*8, intent(in) :: a 
REAL*8 b 
b=a*2 
end subroutine fortran_subroutine
```

To get the .so file (fortran_code.so) I use:

```
f2py -c fortran_code.f -m fortran_code
```

The version of f2py is 2. And the version of Python is 2.7.4

Any help to solve this problem would be very useful.

Thanks!

Comment: If it was possible put your Fortran code in the question, it might be something wrong in it.

Comment: Which version of f2py and Python are you using? `CObjects` have been dropped and replaced by `Capsule` in Python 3.0 [(see here)](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/cporting.html). My guess would be that f2py produces code for Python 2.7 (or earlier) that is interpreted by Python 3.0 (or newer).

Comment: And also add what commands you are using when calling `f2py`.

Comment: The Fortran subroutine code is:

      _SUBROUTINE fortran_subroutine(a)

      REAL*8, intent(in)   :: a

      REAL*8 b

      b=a*2

      end subroutine fortran_subroutine_

To get the .so file (fortran_code.so) I use:

      _f2py -c fortran_code.f -m fortran_code_

The version of f2py is 2.45.241. And the version of Python is 2.7.4.

Comment: Now it is into the question.

Comment: No problems with Python 2.7.3 and F2Py 2 (How do you get this long version number?).

Comment: Doing f2py -v appears to be version 2 :-P

Comment: I'm not too sure about Linux Mint, but most distribution ship both Python 2.7 and 3.x. Can you make sure that Eclipse uses the correct version? You could try running your Python code from a terminal.

Comment: You were right, it works fine in a terminal!!!! In order to make it work in Eclipse I've modified the Python interpreter from Python32 to Python2.7, but still does not work.

Comment: I would like to point out that your `fortran_subroutine` does nothing: there is no output and there is no return value.

Comment: ok, Finally it worked. I only had to define a new module and after modifying the Python Interpreter everything went fine. Thank you all for your help!!!!

Comment: Either delete this question or post an answer -- it's perfectly acceptable to answer your own questions here on SO -- that way the unanswered lists don't get cluttered with questions which have, in fact, been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make it work I had to modify the Python Interpreter from Python 3.2 to Python 2.7 (since f2py produces code for Python 2.7). After editing a new Python module everything worked fine!!!

Thanks for all suggestions and comments, which were really helpful.